# How JSnice do STATISTICAL RENAMING which renames Javascript variables?

Tags: javascript, php

I got a code

```js
  function TRXsOqoPf(pOGsWUBqK) {
    /** @type {string} */
    var tirYFOEZF = "";
    /** @type {number} */
    var RSkZLANHy = ~-1;
    var dubtZzLcb = pOGsWUBqK["length"];
    for (;RSkZLANHy < dubtZzLcb;++RSkZLANHy) {
      var kwrxHKpMQ = pOGsWUBqK["charCodeAt"](RSkZLANHy);
      tirYFOEZF += kwrxHKpMQ >= 55296 ? pOGsWUBqK[RSkZLANHy] : String["fromCharCode"]((kwrxHKpMQ + 55296 - 44613) % 55296);
    }
    return tirYFOEZF;
  }
```

When I use jsnice.org with STATISTICAL RENAMING ?
I get

```js
/**
 * @param {Object} params
 * @return {?}
 */
function TRXsOqoPf(params) {
  /** @type {string} */
  var optsData = "";
  /** @type {number} */
  var i = ~-1;
  var l = params["length"];
  for (;i < l;++i) {
    var bc = params["charCodeAt"](i);
    optsData += bc >= 55296 ? params[i] : String["fromCharCode"]((bc + 55296 - 44613) % 55296);
  }
  return optsData;
}
;
```

How can JSnice do that?
Is there any way for me to rename that variables by using php code?

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: [JSNice](http://jsnice.org) is based on a probabilistic model trained on millions lines of JavaScript code.

If you are interested in more details, please take a look at [Nice2Predict](http://www.nice2predict.org/) website that interactively describes the process.